# Screenshot in Blender with Python is not working

Tags: python, screenshot, blender

I want to take a screenshot from a blender scene and than save it in a file to use it later, but my code is not working and I need help.

This is the code is used:

```
import bpy
import os

# spawn cube
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(scale=(1, 1, 1))

# file path for the screenshotS
filepath = "C:\\Users\\emilk\\Documents\\PcProject\\Screenshots_Blender\\screenshot.png"

# take screenshot
bpy.ops.screen.screenshot_area(filepath=filepath,
                               display_type='DEFAULT',
                               sort_method='',
                               filter_blender=False,
                               filter_backup=False,
                               filter_image=True,
                               filter_movie=False,
                               filter_python=False,
                               filter_font=False,
                               filter_sound=False,
                               filter_text=False,
                               filter_archive=False,
                               filter_btx=False,
                               filter_collada=False,
                               filter_alembic=False,
                               filter_usd=False,
                               filter_obj=False,
                               filter_volume=False,
                               filter_folder=True,
                               filter_blenlib=False,
                               filemode=9,
                               show_multiview=False,
                               use_multiview=False,
                               hide_props_region=True,
                               check_existing=True)
```

And thats what the console says:

```
Read prefs: C:\Users\emilk\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend
Read blend: C:\Users\emilk\Documents\PcProject\project.blend
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emilk\Documents\PcProject\project.blend\Text", line 11, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 132, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties:  enum "" not found in ('DEFAULT', 'FILE_SORT_ALPHA', 'FILE_SORT_EXTENSION', 'FILE_SORT_TIME', 'FILE_SORT_SIZE')
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

I hope anyone can help me!